# How to get value from object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have this code which works.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('form').live('submit', function(){

     // have to do it like this to simulate my problem
     var aform = $(this);

     var dat = { "TITLE" : "55h5", "OWNER" : "fff" };
     $('#template').tmpl(dat).prependTo('#content');

    return false;

  });
});
```

But what I would like is to take the values from `aform` and insert them directly into

```
$('#template').tmpl(  HERE   ).prependTo('#content');
```

The data from the form have do accessed through `aform` to simulate my problem. Can this be done?

Here is the problem illustrated

http://jsfiddle.net/HYLYq/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use [**`.serializeArray()`**](http://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/), and then loop over it to create the right data structure:

```
var data = {},
    values = $(this).serializeArray();

for(var i = values.length; i--;) {
    data[values[i].name] = values[i].value;
}
```

You could do the same with plain JavaScript (is probably faster):

```
var elements = $(this)[0].elements,
    data = {};

for(var i = elements.length; i--;) {
    data[values[i].name] = values[i].value;
}
```

Comment: This is a working example based on felix's answer. I also changed the template so title and owner are lower case - http://jsfiddle.net/HYLYq/5/

Comment: @Sandra: The `name` attributes of the elements are lower case whereas the template variables are upper case. The both have to be the same.

Comment: I think `i` should start with `elments.length - 1`;

Comment: @wong2: No, because `i--` is executed before. I.e. inside the loop body, `i` will be `elments.length - 1` in the first iteration.